# Using pairwise preferences for recommender systems

Tags: recommendation-engine, pagerank

I have a collection of 100k movie ratings, rated by about 1600 users, and each user has rated atleast 20 movies, on a scale from 1 to 5, 5 being the best. Using this, I have to convert these ratings into pairwise preferences, and then make a recommendation to the users using this preference.
The idea behind converting to pairwise preferences is that a user may not accurately rate a movie depending on his/her mood, say for instance he/she may rate a movie a 4 or a 5, depending on various factors like mood, the time when the movie was watched etc. But pairwise preferences are a better way to capture the users taste, and this is the idea I'm working on.
After the  pairwise preferences are generated, I make a directed graph for each user, with nodes being the movies and an edge is from movie1 to movie2 if for the user movie2 was rated better than movie1. From this graph, I compute the pageRank using the popular Page Rank algorithm, and then for each user, I find users similar to him by taking a dot product of the pagerank of movies rated by him and movies rated by others, selecting the top k users. A then make a directed graph using the  pairwise preferences of these users together, and recommend the top movies according to the pagerank so obtained.
The question I have is what kind of modifications I can make to get better accuracy? (I need to use the pairwise preference method, so that is fixed) For instance, what is a way to generate lesser pairwise preferences, without the accuracy decreasing? Any other ideas are appreciated.